# formkey in layered navigation links on search results pages?

Tags: catalogsearch, form-key

I just noticed that the layered navigation links in catalogsearch/result have a formkey embedded in the URL.

The links look like:

```
https://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/index/form_key/8T6hGypNKP98Cdsj/color/3429/q/floral%20doll/?color=3429&q=floral+doll&shape=5681
```

Is this normal?

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?